# What bit hash function does unordered_map use?

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map

What bit hash does `unordered_map` of `C++0x` use by default? `std::hash` function returns `size_t`. Does that mean `unordered_map` uses a 16 bit hash function?

Comment: `sizeof(std::size_t) * CHAR_BIT` bits.

Comment: From your question I'm wondering if you expect the hash function to be something popular like SHA256 or CRC32 -- that isn't the case. Integers for example just hash to themselves.

Comment: @Kerrek Integers probably won't hash to themselves.  That would be terrible for performance if you put sequential integers in an `unordered_map`.

Comment: @Cory: At least that's how GCC and Boost implement `std::hash` for the basic integral types...

Answer (score 3):

`std::unordered_set` uses `std::hash` by default.

If `std::size_t` is 16-bit for you, then I guess it does use a 16-bit hash.  On a 16-bit machine, I'd expect `unordered_map::max_size()` to be low enough that using such a weak hash wouldn't be a problem.